# Simple search in Mongoid using mongoid_search gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to implement search in one of my models. I'm using the gem "mongoid_search" and I'm mixing it with the railscast #240 on search. It seems to be returning an empty array and I can't figure out why. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

My model looks like this:

```
include Mongoid::Search 

attr_accessible :twitterUsername, :twitterName, :twitterLocation, :twitterDescription, :projects

def self.search(search)
    if search
        search_in :twitterUsername, :twitterName, :twitterLocation, :twitterDescription, :projects
    else
        scoped
    end
end
```

My controller:

```
def index
    @users = User.search(params[:search])

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # index.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @users }
    end
end
```

And my view:

```
<%= form_tag users_path, :method => 'get', :id => "users_search" do %>
    <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

UPDATE

I define the twitterUsername (sorry for the bad naming convention) in the model as well:

```
field :provider, :type => String
field :uid, :type => String
field :twitterName, :type => String
field :twitterUsername, :type => String
field :twitterAvatar, :type => String
field :twitterUrl, :type => String
field :twitterPortfolioUrl, :type => String
field :twitterLocation, :type => String
field :twitterDescription, :type => String
field :email, :type => String
field :description, :type => String
field :portfolioUrl, :type => String
field :watchers, :type => Integer
field :inspirations, :type => Integer
field :invitees, :type => Integer
field :shot, :type => String
field :remote_image_url, :type => String
field :hireMe, :type => Boolean
field :projects, :type => Integer
key :twitterUsername


def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
        user.provider = auth['provider']
        user.uid = auth['uid']
        if auth['info']
            user._id = auth['info']['nickname'] || ""
            user.twitterName = auth['info']['name'] || ""
            user.twitterUsername = auth['info']['nickname'] || ""
            user.twitterAvatar = auth['info']['image'] || ""
            user.twitterUrl = auth['info']['urls']['Twitter'] || ""
            user.twitterPortfolioUrl = auth['info']['urls']['Website'] || ""
            user.twitterLocation = auth['info']['location'] || ""
            user.twitterDescription = auth['info']['description'] || ""
        end
    end
end
```

UPDATE 2

If I count the users, it seems to be returning a single user (which is correct since I'm the only one signed up right now):

```
<% if @users.count > 0 %>
  <%= @users.count %>
<% end %>
```

if I do:

```
<% if @users.count > 0 %>
  <%= @users.twitterUsername %>
<% end %>
```

it gives me this error: undefined method `twitterUsername' for User:Class.

UPDATE 3

It gives me an error when I try to run tail log/development.log:

```
± % tail log/development.log                                                                                                             
22:     
app/views/users/index.html.erb:19:in `block in _app_views_users_index_html_erb__1766206529136141992_2490506940'
app/views/users/index.html.erb:18:in `each'
app/views/users/index.html.erb:18:in `_app_views_users_index_html_erb__1766206529136141992_2490506940'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7:in `index'


Rendered /Users/holgersindbaek/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125-perf/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (5.3ms)
Rendered /Users/holgersindbaek/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125-perf/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.2ms)
Rendered /Users/holgersindbaek/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125-perf/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (13.9ms)
```

UPDATE 4

I get this in my console if when I run a search:

```
Started GET "/users?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=holgersindbaek" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-10     23:24:55 +0200
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"holgersindbaek"}
MONGODB (1ms) flow04_development['users'].find({:_id=>"holgersindbaek"}).limit(-1).sort([[:_id, :asc]])
Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for User:Class):
22:         <% if current_user == user %>
23: 
24:         <% else %>
25:           <% if current_user.follower_of?(user) %>
26:             <%= link_to "Unfollow", unfollow_user_path(user), :remote => true,     :class=>'unfollow' %>
27:           <% else %>
28:             <%= link_to "Follow", follow_user_path(user), :remote => true, :class=>'follow' %>
app/views/users/index.html.erb:25:in `block in _app_views_users_index_html_erb__83132873031271873_2505118720'
app/views/users/index.html.erb:18:in `each'
app/views/users/index.html.erb:18:in `_app_views_users_index_html_erb__83132873031271873_2505118720'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

Comment: Does your model actually define the twitter_username field, or only use attr_accssible? (note, you should switch from twitterUsername to twitter_username).

Comment: Ya... I'm defining it in the User model (look at update). I simply can't understand why it's returning something empty. Where would you go from here in relation to trouble-shooting?

Comment: Are the items in User already in the database when you added mongoid_search, or did they exist and you're adding mongoid_search to existing data?

Comment: They were already in the database. I'll just try and drop the table and sign up again... 2 sec.

Comment: Still no-go. Dropped the table, signed up again, checked in the database and saw 1 user (me), saw he had a twitterUsername of HolgerSindbaek and searched on it. It just gived me an error-page with: undefined method `id' for User:Class. What would be your next move in such a situation?

Comment: I can post the view as well, if that would help?

Comment: You wrote `<%= @users.twitterUsername %>` ... but you should be doing <%= @users.first.twitterUsername %> so get the first user's twitterUsername

Comment: Ya, whoops. It gives me the error even though I'm taking it through the each loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not doing the search in an if/else statement. Ended up doing:

```
search_in :twitterUsername, :twitterName, :twitterLocation, :twitterDescription
```

As simple as that. I'm using the index for search, since I'm not using that for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as I see it, is that mongoid-search adds an attribute named "_keywords" to your document when you save it. It then searches documents based on "_keywords"

So, you effectively need to reindex the collection. Try this:

Add to user model

```
field :reindexed, type: Boolean, default: false
```

run the following

```
User.where(reindexed: false).each {|u| u.reindexed = true; u.save}
```

Then when you search, it should be happy.

Comment: I see where you are getting at, but that shouldn't be a problem when I dropped all the users from the database and signed up again. Then mongoid-search should index it automatically, shouldn't it? If not, how should I run the second piece of code? I'm still a bit new to rails. Thanks for the answer btw :-).

Comment: Everything looks configured correctly, I'm not seeing the problem.

Comment: Me neither. That's the big problem. I haven't got a clue why it's not working. Could it be some other gems that are causing some problems or what else could it be?

Comment: It could be that the user is not being saved. Or there is a default scope, or the actual search query is returning 0 results. thoughts: do a "tail log/development.log" and paste in the mongo query that's being run. Also verify that User.count > 0

Comment: I tried to make a count on the @users to see if it returns any users and it does. I don't know how to do the: "tail log/development.log" and paste in the mongo query that's being run. Can you explain?

Comment: Btw... I have "scoped" in my search model in the else statement, but that shouldn't have any effect on it, should it?

Comment: Run your search and in the command line, run `tail log/development.log`

Comment: It gives me an error when I run the tail log/development.log. What's the reason for that you think?

Comment: How do I get to the console... Isn't the console when I cd into the app? Sorry for being such a noob. Glad for your patience :-).

Comment: Sorry man, there's too much in flux here to accurately help on SO. If you want to engage for training ($), contact me at comalproductions.com.... You may want to try SOLR (sunspot_rails) instead of mongoid_search.

Comment: If I write script/console, it tells me there's no such file or directory. I'm using oh-my-zsh, if that has anything to do with it? It would really mean a lot to me, if you could put me on the right path. Now I'm a bit noobish on this. Maybe we could have a chat about it?

Comment: I'm a student so I have no $$$, sorry. Thanks for the help though. If I get the console working (it throws me an error when I do rails console: unexpected $end require 'awesome_print'), I'll post the output of the tailing. Would love to hear what you think of that if you feel like telling me at that time.

Comment: Managed to tail the thing. Got the console and the irb mixed up... sorry. Does this tell you anything?

Comment: It tells me line 25 in your view is wrong. where are you assigning the user variable?

Comment: I'm assigning it in the User model, I guess. not sure what assigning means?

Comment: It seems to be always looking for "holgersindbaek", even though I'm not searching for it... weird: flow04_development['users'].find({:_id=>"holgersindbaek"})

Comment: How can I check what it's really returning? If it's an array or what it is. If I do <%= @users.first %>, it just writes "User".

Comment: I know you're new, so it all seems complex... But you need to peel back the complexity and build a rails app that shows simple data to the screen, and then add in searching. As it stands now, you have many things wrong.

Comment: I have many things wrong? Really? Which? I added the search functionality earlier, but then it failed at some point. How would you go about troubleshooting this?

Comment: I would replace your search function with User.limit(10).all to get the views correct